# C++: How to get iterator type from defined container object

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, containers, typedef

I have a code In a form:

```
unordered_set<pair<int,int>,CustomHash> Edges;
typedef unordered_set<pair<int,int>,CustomHash>::iterator EdgesIt;
...
for(auto it=Edges.begin();it!=Edges.end();it++){
    list<EdgesIt> List;
}
```

etc. How can I avoid defining a new type EdgesIt to be used in List declaration and get it in some smarter way, for example:

```
list<Edges::iterator_type> List;
```

InteliSense only suggests `Edges::iterator` which is defined as `typedef std::iterator pair<int,int> iterator`. More to say, it doesn't work. I also tried to use `unordered_set::iterator`, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. `typedef Edges::iterator EdgesIt;` is correct.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `Edges` is not the name of the type in the above question, so `typedef Edges::iterator EdgesIt;` is not correct. It would need to be `typedef decltype(Edges)::iterator EdgesIt`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Edges` is the name of object, not the name of the class. You can't get the nested `typedef` from it directly like `Edges::iterator`.

You can use [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) (since C++11) to get the type you want (i.e. `unordered_set<pair<int,int>,CustomHash>`).

```
list<decltype(Edges)::iterator> List; 
// same as list<unordered_set<pair<int,int>,CustomHash>::iterator> List;
```